# Problem to run my apps on Android Studio because of image is png instead of xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, png

I have problem to run my apps on Android Studio because of my image is png instead of xml. I tried to change the extension from .png to .xml but its still not working. Any step that I miss ?

The error is

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: The file name must end with .xml

Comment: Please post any `stacktrace` or `errors` your getting out of the build process as `.png` is a valid image format to use in `Android` right out of the box.

Comment: Sorry. I already update on my post

Comment: What are you trying to use the `.png` for? Can you post that?

Comment: Your `png` image or something else (not `xml`) might be in wrong folder. Try putting it in `res/drawable/`.